# How not to display tax in english store view

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, tax

I have a site with 2 store views, one in my native language and the other in english. Is it possible not to display tax when in cart in the english store view?

Answer (score 0):

`System > Configuration > [Sales] Tax > Shopping cart display` , select English from `Current Configuration Scope`, expand `Shopping Cart Display` and uncheck `Use Website [STORE VIEW]` for every option you need to adjust. Hope this will help

Comment: thank you for your answer but i have already tried that and nothing changed.